# Reducing Garbage Collection on Java Web Socket

Tags: java, websocket, garbage-collection

I've been trying to set up a market data feed handler that sources from multiple crypto exchanges. Most of these crypto exchanges provide web socket connectivity to stream quotes and trades. I am using a java-websocket (https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket) which implements web socket response on a callback like `public void onMessage(String s)`. Now, we know this will invoke a new thread to run the callback when a message is received, not to mention that every `String` message that we receive into this call is subject to garbage collection later.

Given above, I have the following question.

1. Is there no way to implement the web socket messaging in a single-threaded fashion (as opposed to a new thread spawning on each callback)? Any techniques or libraries that can be integrated for this purpose?
2. When messages are received to the callback, is there a way to reduce garbage by somehow reusing byte arrays? Each message will be distinct `String` and it seems preventing their creations to limit the memory usage seems impossible, but want to see if anyone has any ideas.

Hoping to learn ideas and techniques to make this Java process zero gc.

Comment: 1. Look at java NIO for how to make a webbserver using few threads. 2. NIO might help you here to. Look at buffers. But i think you will get some strings created anyway,  but buffers might reduce them.

Comment: Free garbage is nearly impossible (if you achieve it, please let me know how !). Providing you do not store references to that `String` objects, they will be mark as unreachable and collected in the next Young Collection. That should not be a mayor concern as that is regular Java workflow memory management.

Comment: Thank you for the comments, guys. Will give NIO a try for web socket.